# Web API 2. Получение значения параметра из запроса

Tags: asp.net-web-api

**Контроллер**

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetData(FormRequest formRequest)
{
    ...
}
```

**FormRequest**

```
public class FormRequest
{
    public int Param1 { get; set; }
    public int Param2 { get; set; }
}
```

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "DefaultApi",
                "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

В POST-запросе передаются параметры с именами `$Param1` и `$Param2`

Как замапить значения этих параметров на свойства объекта `FormRequest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему реализацией интерфейса `IModelBinder`